# Extracting data from different dates with subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below query built and one of the requirements has changed.

The overall where clause of the query looks a looks at anything paid out in the last 12 months

```sql
WHERE (C.DATE_PAID_OUT >= DATEADD(month, - 12, GETDATE()))
```

However one of the columns `(A.EXCESS_MILEAGE_CHARGE_VALUE)` needs to be based on anything completed in the last 12 months

```sql
(C.DATE_CONTRACT_COMPLETED >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 12, 0))
```

Without having to rewrite the whole query is there a way this can be easily achieved so just the A.EXCESS_MILEAGE_CHARGE_VALUE is based on the completed date and the remainder of the columns on date paid out.

Thanks in advance

```sql
SELECT D.ACCOUNT_MANAGER_NAME,
       DG.DEALER_GROUP_DESCRIPTION,
       D.DEALER_ID,
       D.DEALER_NAME,
       D.IS_ACTIVE AS DEALER_ACTIVE,
       D.SUPPLIER_FLAG_NEW,
       D.BROKER_FLAG,
       C.SOURCE,
       C.IS_Promo,
       C.CONTRACT_NUMBER,
       C.CONTRACT_STATUS_DESCRIPTION,
       C.EARLY_SETTLEMENT_GROUP_DESCRIPTION,
       C.EARLY_SETTLEMENT_REASON_DESCRIPTION,
       C.DATE_PAID_OUT,
       C.DATE_CONTRACT_COMPLETED,
       C.EXCESS_MILEAGE_VALUE_DEBIT,
       CD.CUSTOMER_NAME,
       ISNULL(Respond.COMPLAINTS, 0) AS TCF_COMPLAINTS,
       Respond.Case_receipt_date AS COMPLAINT_RECEIPT_DATE,
       Respond.Business_area AS COMPLAINT_SOURCE,
       C.FINANCE_COMMISSION_VALUE + C.FIXED_COMMISSION_VALUE + C.VB_DEALER_COMMISSION_VALUE + C.VB_GROUP_COMMISSION_VALUE - C.DEALER_SUBSIDY_VALUE AS TOTAL_COMMISSION,
       ROUND(C.INTEREST_VALUE, 2) + C.ADMINISTRATION_FEE_VALUE AS TOTAL_CHARGES,
       C.INTEREST_VALUE,
       RR.[Created Date] AS SURVEY_DATE,
       ISNULL(RR.FCAAS1 + RR.FCAAS2 + RR.FCAAS3, 0) AS CUSTOMER_SATISFACTION_RATING,
       A.EXCESS_MILEAGE_CHARGE_VALUE,
       ISNULL(EXCESS_MILEAGE.PCP_CONTRACTS, 0) AS PCP_CONTRACTS,
       ISNULL(EXCESS_MILEAGE.PCH_CONTRACTS, 0) AS PCH_CONTRACTS,
       VUL.VUL_CONTRACT_SOURCE,
       VUL.MIN_AUDIT_DATE,
       ISNULL(VUL.VULNERABLE, 0) AS Vulnerable
FROM dbo.FDW_CONTRACT C
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.FDW_CUSTOMER_DETAIL CD ON C.UNIQUE_PRIME_CUSTOMER_ID = CD.CUSTOMER_UNIQUE_ID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.FDW_DEALER D ON D.DEALER_ID = C.DEALER_ID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.FDW_DEALER_GROUP DG ON DG.DEALER_GROUP_ID = D.DEALER_GROUP_ID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.FDW_ASSET A ON C.CONTRACT_NUMBER = A.CONTRACT_NUMBER
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT R.Case_receipt_date,
                             R.Agreement_number,
                             d.DEALER_ID,
                             R.Business_area,
                             COUNT(*) AS COMPLAINTS
                      FROM dbo.FDW_RESPOND_COMBINED R
                           INNER JOIN dbo.FDW_CONTRACT c ON c.CONTRACT_NUMBER = R.Agreement_number
                           INNER JOIN dbo.FDW_DEALER d ON d.DEALER_ID = c.DEALER_ID
                      WHERE (R.Complaint_type IN ('Affordability (Dealer Mis-selling)', 'Age (Affordability)', 'Agreement type (Dealer Mis-selling)', 'Financial (Affordability)', 'Mileage Allowance (Dealer Mis-selling)', 'VAPs (Dealer Mis-selling)', 'Vulnerable customer (Dealer Mis-selling)', 'Wrong vehicle/spec (Dealer Mis-selling)'))
                        AND (R.Feedback_type = 'Complaint')
                        AND (R.Complaint_tier = 'Main')
                        AND (R.Aspect_outcome IN ('Upheld', 'Partially Upheld'))
                        AND (R.Case_material_Impact <> 'NO')
                      GROUP BY R.Case_receipt_date,
                               d.DEALER_ID,
                               R.Agreement_number,
                               R.Business_area) Respond ON Respond.DEALER_ID = D.DEALER_ID
                                                       AND Respond.Agreement_number = C.CONTRACT_NUMBER
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.FDW_RR_CSD RR ON C.CONTRACT_NUMBER = RR.[Contract Number]
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DD.DEALER_ID,
                             COUNT(CASE WHEN FP.FINANCE_TYPE_DESCRIPTION IN ('PCP', 'Personal Contract Purchase') THEN 1 END) AS PCP_CONTRACTS,
                             COUNT(CASE WHEN FP.FINANCE_TYPE_DESCRIPTION IN ('Personal Contract Hire', 'Contract Hire') THEN 1 END) AS PCH_CONTRACTS
                      FROM dbo.FDW_DEALER DD
                           RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.FDW_CONTRACT CC ON CC.DEALER_ID = DD.DEALER_ID
                           LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.FDW_FINANCE_PRODUCTS FP ON FP.PLAN_ID = CC.PLAN_ID
                      WHERE (CC.DATE_PAID_OUT >= DATEADD(MONTH, -48, GETDATE()))
                      GROUP BY DD.DEALER_ID) EXCESS_MILEAGE ON EXCESS_MILEAGE.DEALER_ID = D.DEALER_ID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT C.SOURCE AS VUL_CONTRACT_SOURCE,
                             C.CONTRACT_NUMBER,
                             C.DATE_PAID_OUT AS CONTRACT_START_DATE,
                             COUNT(*) AS VULNERABLE,
                             ISNULL(MIN_DATE.MIN_AUDIT_DATE, C.DATE_PAID_OUT) AS MIN_AUDIT_DATE
                      FROM dbo.FDW_CONTRACT C
                           LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.FDW_CUSTOMER_DETAIL CD ON C.UNIQUE_PRIME_CUSTOMER_ID = CD.CUSTOMER_UNIQUE_ID
                           LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.FDW_DEALER D ON D.DEALER_ID = C.DEALER_ID
                           LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.FDW_DEALER_GROUP DG ON DG.DEALER_GROUP_ID = D.DEALER_GROUP_ID
                           LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,
                                                   MIN(DATE_AUDIT) AS MIN_AUDIT_DATE
                                            FROM dbo.FDW_AUDIT A
                                            WHERE (AUDIT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION = 'Customer')
                                              AND (AUDIT_FIELD = 'CUSTOMER STATUS')
                                              AND (AUDIT_NEW_VALUE LIKE '%22%')
                                            GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID) MIN_DATE ON MIN_DATE.CUSTOMER_ID = CD.SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID
                      WHERE (C.DATE_PAID_OUT >= DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE()))
                        AND CD.IS_VULNERABLE = 'Y'
                      GROUP BY C.DATE_PAID_OUT,
                               C.SOURCE,
                               MIN_DATE.MIN_AUDIT_DATE,
                               C.CONTRACT_NUMBER) VUL ON VUL.CONTRACT_number = C.Contract_number
WHERE (C.DATE_PAID_OUT BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY C.CONTRACT_NUMBER,
         C.CONTRACT_STATUS_DESCRIPTION,
         C.DATE_PAID_OUT,
         D.ACCOUNT_MANAGER_NAME,
         D.DEALER_NAME,
         CD.CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME,
         CD.CUSTOMER_FAMILY_NAME,
         C.SOURCE,
         CD.SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID,
         DG.DEALER_GROUP_DESCRIPTION,
         D.IS_ACTIVE,
         D.SUPPLIER_FLAG_NEW,
         D.BROKER_FLAG,
         D.DEALER_ID,
         C.DATE_CONTRACT_COMPLETED,
         CD.CUSTOMER_NAME,
         C.EXCESS_MILEAGE_VALUE_DEBIT,
         Respond.Case_receipt_date,
         Respond.Business_area,
         C.FINANCE_COMMISSION_VALUE,
         C.FIXED_COMMISSION_VALUE,
         C.VB_DEALER_COMMISSION_VALUE,
         C.VB_GROUP_COMMISSION_VALUE,
         C.DEALER_SUBSIDY_VALUE,
         C.INTEREST_VALUE,
         C.ADMINISTRATION_FEE_VALUE,
         C.IS_Promo,
         C.EARLY_SETTLEMENT_GROUP_DESCRIPTION,
         C.EARLY_SETTLEMENT_REASON_DESCRIPTION,
         C.INTEREST_VALUE,
         Respond.COMPLAINTS,
         RR.[Created Date],
         RR.FCAAS1,
         RR.FCAAS2,
         RR.FCAAS3,
         A.EXCESS_MILEAGE_CHARGE_VALUE,
         EXCESS_MILEAGE.PCP_CONTRACTS,
         EXCESS_MILEAGE.PCH_CONTRACTS,
         VUL.VUL_CONTRACT_SOURCE,
         VUL.MIN_AUDIT_DATE,
         VUL.VULNERABLE;
```

Comment: *Good* use of line breaks and white space is a wonderful thing, it made your unreadable mess, readable.

Comment: Why do you have that giant `GROUP BY` clause? There's no aggregation in your (outer) query.

Comment: It's not my query, it was built by someone who has left the business and I've been asked to make a change to it

Comment: But if you are now the "owner" of said query you need to understand the "whys", Andrea. The `GROUP BY` makes no sense there, as there's no aggregation.

Comment: If I remove the Group by I get the following error msg:    Column 'VUL.VULNERABLE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: `VUL.VULNERABLE` isn't in an aggregate function though. Sounds like there are other problems in that query that need addressing; or that isn't the full query.

Comment: It's the full query. I've removed the group by now. Are you able to assist with the question posted?

Comment: Personally, I would suggest you should be rewritting the whole query. I know you don't want to, but the fact you have a `GROUP BY` and no aggregation is a clear sign of underlying problems. I doubt that query is doing what anyone *thinks* it is. *We* can't rewrite it for you though; we don't have access to your instance, nor know the goal of the query.

Comment: okay thank you, it will have to be re-written then